# How can I get consecutively the same dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

My data is like this, status is 0 or 1, uid is user id.

```
   uid   |timestamp |status
   1     |1         | 0
   2     |3         | 1
   1     |2         | 1
   2     |1         | 0
   1     |3         | 1
   2     |2         | 0
   2     |4         | 0
```

I wanna data partitioned by uid and order by timestamp asc.

```
   uid   |timestamp |status
   1     |1         | 0
   1     |2         | 1
   1     |3         | 1
   2     |1         | 0
   2     |2         | 0
   2     |3         | 1
   2     |4         | 0
```

And get all consecutively the same status and conbine them to do other things.
Sorry, my English is ...shit.
The rusult is like below:

```
   uid   |status  |timestamps-asc-order
   1     |(0)     | (1)
   1     |(1,1)   | (2,2)
   2     |(0,0)   | (1,2)
   2     |(1)     | (3)
   2     |(0)     | (4)
```

I can do partition and order with window function.
But then, how to get consecutively same status ?

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("uid").orderBy($"timestamp".asc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You are looking for the [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/index.html#collect_list) function.

You should be able to achieve what you ask with a

`df.withColumn("timestamps-asc-order", collect_list("timestamp").over(Window.partitionBy("uid").orderBy("timestamp"))`